# Alter" VLOOKUP" code to run Cell by Cell not on entire range

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I am tring to alter this code `FindReplace_With_Offset_1` to `FindReplace_With_Offset_2`

`FindReplace_With_Offset_1` Run on a Col Range and it works fine

I need `FindReplace_With_Offset_2` to run only on each Cell in the Col Range i.e. I need each cell to be its own range, when I run it I get `#NAME?` for every Cell with value `#N/A`

Thanks

```
Sub FindReplace_With_Offset_1()
Dim wsFR As Worksheet, wsT As Worksheet
Dim tLR As Long, i As Long

 Set wsT = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("XXX")
Set wsFR = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ZZZ")


With wsT
     tLR = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
      With .Range("B2:B" & tLR) 'The Offset Range
           .Value = _
           "=VLOOKUP(D2," & wsFR.Range("D1").CurrentRegion.Address(1, 1, , 1) & ",2,0)"
           .Value = .Value
      End With
End With
End Sub
```

Code2

```
Sub FindReplace_With_Offset_2()
Dim wsFR As Worksheet, wsT As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range, aCell As Range
Dim tLR As Long, i As Long

Set wsT = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("XXX")
Set wsFR = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ZZZ")

 With wsT
        tLR = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
         Set Rng = .Range("A2:A" & tLR)

           For Each aCell In Rng
              If aCell.text = "#N/A" Then
                 aCell.Value = _
                 "=VLOOKUP(aCell," &   wsFR.Range("C1").CurrentRegion.Address(1, 1, , 1) & ",2,0)"
                 aCell.Value = aCell.Value
              Else
                 aCell = aCell
              End If
           Next aCell
  End With
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you're trying to put the code to read a error value, and for the excel the cell value isn't the text "#N/A", try to use the IfError formula to run the verification on the desired cell, like this:

```
If WorksheetFunction.IfError(aCell,"Error") = "Error" Then
```